# Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow R$ be continuous such that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow R$ be continuous such that $f(a)=f(b)$. Show that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exist distinct $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $|x-y|<\epsilon$ and $f(x)=f(y)$.

I can not solve this problem. Please if anybody help me, I will be very pleased.

Comment: Use fact that $f$ has an extremum point in $(a,b)$.(if it isn't constant of course).

Comment: ok, fine, i apologize for my wrong intervention :-)

Answer (score 8):

One may suppose that $f$ is not constant. Let $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f$ has an extremum at $c$, ($c$ exists by the fact that $f(a)=f(b)$). Let $\varepsilon>0$, small, and suppose that $f$ is injective on $\displaystyle J_{\varepsilon}=(c-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, c+\frac{\varepsilon}{2})\subset ]a,b[$. Then as $f$ is continuous, $f$ is strictly monotonic on $J_{\varepsilon}$, et this contradict the fact that $f$ has an extremum at $c$. This show the assertion.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: Thank you!

Comment: suppose $f$ is not injective, then what can we conclude?

Comment: Have you thinked about it @user154990?

Comment: @user154990: if $f$ is not injective, Then there exists $x,y\in J_{\varepsilon}$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ and  $x\not =y$, and clearly we have $|x-y|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: If $f$ has extremum at $c$, then obviously $f$ is not strictly monotone on $J_{\epsilon}$. But how will we show $f$ has extremum?

Comment: As $f$ is not constant and $f(a)=f(b)$,  (and if $f$ takes  values $>f(a)$ for example; the same if $f$ takes values $<f(a)$) if $M$ is ${\rm Sup}(f(x))$ (I use the fact that $f$ is continuous), then there exits $c$ such that $f(c)=M$, and $c\in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume without loss of generality that $f$ is not constant. Let $c$ be a extremum point of $f$ in $(a,b)$ (why this point exists?), for example, let's assume it is a maximum. Take $\epsilon>0$ small and consider the numbers $$m_1=\min_{\Large{x\in [c-\frac{\epsilon}2,c]}} f(x),\ m_2=\min_{\Large{x\in[c,c+\frac{\epsilon}2]}} f(x).$$

If $m_1=f(c)$ then $f(x)=f(c)$ for all $x\in [c-\frac{\epsilon}2,c]$ therefore, just take $x,y\in [c-\frac{\epsilon}2,c]$ with $x\neq y$

If $m_2=f(c)$ then $f(x)=f(c)$ for all $x\in [c,c+\frac{\epsilon}2]$ therefore, just take $x,y\in [c,c+\frac{\epsilon}2]$ with $x\neq y$

Thus, assume that $m_1<f(c)$ and $m_2<f(c)$. Let $m=\max\{m_1,m_2\}$ and note that for any number $d\in ]m,f(c)[$, there is $x\in ]c-\frac{\epsilon}2,c[$, $y\in ]c,c+\frac{\epsilon}2[$, such that $f(x)=f(y)=d$, and $x\neq y$, $|x-y|<\epsilon$.

Comment: It fails for two reasons: first, your definition of $x,y$ does not guarantee that $x\neq y$ (intervals are closed and contain $c$). Then, if you take open intervals, it fails if the extremum is flat, and $c$ is on the boundary of this flat piece: on one side, the function is strictly decreasing, on the other it's constant. So $m=f(c)$, you should take $c=x$ and you have to go on the flat side to find $y$ (or the other way around if you are on the other border of the flat piece). If think that, as is (with the first reason set apart), the proof does work only for a single extremum (a "pike").

Comment: Actually, I had more or less the same idea, then I thought of this flat function problem, and I checked Kelenner's proof. That's why I find it so nice: it doesn't even have to care for this.

Comment: I see @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. So I should deal with the case where $x=c=y$. I think it can be done, with some effort. Let me try to fix it. If it get to boring I will delete thi answer. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Dear @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I can assume that $f$ is not constant in any neighbourhood of $c$, so indeed, my argument does work, because $d\in (m,f(c))$. What do you think?

Comment: But you can't assume that: think of a function made of an increasing part, a flat line segment, and a decreasing part. Its maximum is the whole segment part. So anyway you chose $c$, the function *is* constant on a neighborhood of $c$. Of course you can still find $x,y$ so that the ttheorem holds, but then $f(x)=f(y)=f(c)$, and the three point all belong to the line segment. And if there is only a "pike", your proof works (if you fix the closed interval problem). But you have to take those two cases into account.

Comment: Please @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, take a look now.

Comment: I made some modifications, it's simpler to follow than a long comment. Do you agree with them? Of course, feel free to revert or to modify my edit ;-) I think it's ok now, and it's the answer I was too lazy to write down! +1 of course.